# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Googlemap>

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I am working on a nuxt project, and I'm trying to build a map component using google maps and the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps. I have installed the plugin using npm , and I've got in working when my index.vue page looks like:

```
<template>
   <div>


<br>
       <VideoCarousel/>
       <!-- <Googlemap/> -->
           <GmapMap :center="{lat:10, lng:10}" :zoom="7" map-type-id="terrain" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"/>
       <Panel/>
       <Four/>
       </div> 
</template>

<script>
import Three from '~/components/section3.vue'
import Four from '~/components/section4.vue'
import VuetifyLogo from '~/components/VuetifyLogo.vue'
import Menu from '~/components/menu.vue'
import VideoCarousel from '~/components/video-carousel.vue'
import Panel from '~/components/panel.vue'
import GoogleMap from '~/components/googleMap.vue'


export default {

  components: {
    Three,
    Four,
    Panel,
    VideoCarousel,
    GoogleMap
  }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

But when I uncomment the  component, no map is generated. In devtools I see:

[image]

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Googlemap> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

What am I doing wrong?

googleMap.vue

```
<template>
  <GmapMap
  :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
  :zoom="7"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
>

</GmapMap>

</template>


<script>


export default {
     name:'GoogleMap'

}

</script>


<style>

</style>
```

The plugin in the nuxt plugin folder is:

/plugins/google-maps.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: "YOUR_API_TOKEN",
    libraries: "places"
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct: `import GoogleMap from '~/components/googleMap.vue'`

Comment: Also, depending on your local set up try resarting your local server, on vue/cli v3 I have had some issues with hot reload. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2051

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com , Thanks. as far as I can tell this is correct (its the same path as the other components. ) I restarted the dev server without success. I've updated the question

Comment: Per the error, GoogleMap is not registered correct, double check case? Also, per the error message try adding a name: 'GoogleMaps' to the export object of googleMap.vue. `export default { name: ''GoogleMaps }`.

Comment: I had tried that earlier (I've added it above). No change.

Comment: OK, seems to be working now. I changed all the references from 'GoogleMap' to 'MyMap' in index.vue . Nothing needs to be exported in the googleMap.vue component

Comment: Good to hear it, certainly sounds like a name space collision somewhere in the codebase.